# How can I set the height of my website to be the same height as the visible browser window, with no vertical scrolling?

Tags: website-design, css, html, dimensions

I want to design a portfolio website, and I don't want it to scroll vertically.

What are the dimensions for this kind of website, like the standard browser height?

How can I create a website that's the same size as the visible height of the browser?

Comment: Note that web sites scroll. That's kinda one of the defining aspects of the medium. It may make more sense to embrace that rather than fight that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days webdesignerd tend to use responsive values. So make it responsive by using %. Although this makes using images tricky

Comment: thanks for the reply.but there must be some value while designing the height of the website.

Comment: @arsa no there must not be. You can no way know  what size or shape  the recipients screen is going to be

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Responsive web sites are about handling variable width...not height.

Answer (score 3):

## The dimensions are *variable*.

User Joojaa is correct when they say that "You can no way know what size or shape the recipients screen is going to be."

You cannot set any explicit value in your CSS, because if you want to consistently support all browsers, you have no way of knowing what size it's going to be.

I'm going to give you one method, using just HTML and CSS. I have briefly tested a basic version in Chrome and IE. It's fine back to IE7, and then the vertical alignment drops out, but the single page with no scrolling remains intact as far back as IE5(!).

Here's an image of the result (click on the image to go to a working example on jsFiddle):

[image]

In case my example link goes dead, here's the code for my mockup:

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="centered-container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="name">
                Eileen Dover
            </div>
            “I'm part of the 21<sup>st</sup> century now.<br> I have an online portfolio!”
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="#">Click here to see some of my awesome work!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#191970;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.centered-container {
    position:absolute;
    left:5%;
    right:5%;
    top:5%;
    bottom:5%;
    background:#fff;
    display:table;
    width:89%;
    height:89%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.content {
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:2.500em;
    color:#191970;
    border-top:4px ridge #4c4ca3;
    border-left:4px ridge #4c4ca3;
    border-bottom:4px groove #4c4ca3;
    border-right:4px groove #4c4ca3;
}

.name {
    font-size:3.500em;
    font-weight:700;
    padding:0.050em 0;  
}
```

This is the most I can do for you at the moment. I have no idea how much HTML, CSS or JavaScript you know, but if you really want to make this, you should learn a bit and make a plan. This kind of website will only work with certain kinds of designs. Namely, ones with minimal text.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: It's not a bad try, but note that I can easily make it scroll vertically by narrowing my browser a bit. Ultimately, if there is more content than can fit, you will get scroll bars. There's ways around this with variable sized content--and that can work to an extent--but I'd still argue that it's fighting the medium rather than embracing it. Not that that is always a bad thing, mind you.

Comment: If I had a compelling enough reason, I think I could make it work quite consistently - with a much more complex framework - but I sincerely hope nobody ever gives me that reason. Thank you for the upvote *(I assume)*. :)

Comment: The answer is definitely worth an upvote! I think your last comment sums it up well, actually "If there is a compelling enough reason..." Only the OP can answer that, of course, but I think it's a good rhetorical question for the OP to think about.

Comment: @DA01 I might misunderstand entirely, but I would say that achieving this is impossible, unless the content is _tiny_. Or am I getting it all wrong?

Comment: @RandomO'Reilly I suppose it could be done if the content, itself, scales. So you could use javascript to determine the height of the viewport, then shrink the scale of entire page (perhaps using CSS's `zoom` style) until you can determine (via JS) that the content fits sans scrolling.

Comment: @DA01 yes, you are right there, of course. But I guess it will all boil down to what content, really. There would have to be tiny amounts of content on each "page" (an image with text would probably render the text so small it would be unreadable.) Then you would get a ludicrous amount of JS and endless clicking instead of scrolling. So, it is possible, but really only for a _very_ limited kind of content (a "quote of the day"-type thing would work.).

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter yes, it is that portfolio-bit that makes me think this is a _particularly_ bad idea, see my comment above. It is _possible_ but very unlikely to be user friendly or practical. I would like to see the question elaborated a bit more, unless that happens i do not see this as a great learning-opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it does not scroll vertically"?

That you do not *want* it to scroll vertically, or that for some reason it is "fixed"?

There is no such thing as guidelines for web page withs and heights anymore. As user2725502 and Joojaa points out: the massive variety of devices makes this wildly impractical if not directly impossible to do sensibly.

Look into *responsive* design. I would suggest you use a framework; this will save you masses of time and loads of headaches. They have already sorted out the responsive part. To create a responsive site from scratch, taking into account every single option for devices is ... well... pointless, as very smart people have already solved this problem for us. Personally, I use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), but there are many other options.

Comment: -1 for promoting Bootstrap.  There's no need to take "into account every single option for devices".  Responsiveness should be dictated by the content, which is not nearly as difficult as you're making it out to be.

Comment: Good that you are telling my why you downvote, but I am merely _suggesting_ Bootstrap. I suggest you write your own - and a better answer. I have created all kinds of complex applications from scratch, and I have lectured on both methods. I am merely suggesting what I think will be useful for the OP.

Comment: Bootstrap is perfectly acceptable recommendation. No need for the downvote.